# Multiple mutable borrows when using result of a method call

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

In this simplified code, I have two important structs: `Owner` takes ownership of an object, adds it to a Vec, and returns a reference to it; `RefKeeper` just holds references to objects in a Vec. `Owner` also has a `RefKeeper`.

```rust
struct Foo(i32);

struct Owner<'o> {
    list: Vec<Foo>,
    refkeeper: RefKeeper<'o>,
}

impl<'o> Owner<'o> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            list: Vec::new(),
            refkeeper: RefKeeper::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, me: Foo) -> &Foo {
        self.list.push(me);
        return self.list.last().unwrap();
    }

    pub fn add_ref(&mut self, me: &'o Foo) {
        self.refkeeper.add(me);
    }
}

struct RefKeeper<'ro> {
    list: Vec<&'ro Foo>,
}

impl<'ro> RefKeeper<'ro> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { list: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, me: &'ro Foo) {
        self.list.push(me);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut owner = Owner::new();
    let a1 = Foo(1);
    let a1_ref = owner.add(a1);

    // this variant doesn't work
    owner.add_ref(a1_ref);

    // let mut refkeeper = RefKeeper::new();
    // refkeeper.add(a1_ref);

    // let a2 = Foo(2);
    // owner.add_ref(&a2);
}
```

Two variants work: if I make `RefKeeper` externally, I can store the ref returned by `Owner::add`; on the other hand, if I make a new object (`a2`), I can store `&a2` in `owner.refkeeper` with no problem. Why does the other variant give me this error?

```rust
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `owner` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:46:5
   |
43 |     let a1_ref = owner.add(a1);
   |                  ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
46 |     owner.add_ref(a1_ref);
   |     ^^^^^         ------ first borrow later used here
   |     |
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this pattern? I'm under the impression that there should be no issue with lifetimes because all the borrows are being used in the same object.

Comment: What is the actual goal of `RefKeeper`? The API you've defined will have loads of problems as-is. Keep in mind that as long as a reference to a value in `list` exists, you can never insert another entry into that list, so by adding an item and then adding it to refkeeper, you'd be making it impossible to add any more items.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `Owner::add` returns a reference that is bound to the lifetime of `&mut self`. So as long as the return value exists (`a1_ref`) then the `&mut self` reference does too. So calling `add_ref` fails because it requires another `mut self` reference of that same instance.

You can either have one mutable reference, or many immutable references.

The reason calling `refkeeper.add` and then `owner.add_ref` is not giving you the same issue is because adding to `refkeeper` does not require another reference to `owner`.

You might want to look at [std::rc::Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html).